# Not able to log in via firestore

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to make a log-in app with firebase firestore. The problem is that when I click on the log in button, nothing happens. I was previously able to log me in, but now I suddenly cannot. 
The page reloads when I click on the log in button. What may be my mistake? Why doesn't it work anymore?

In the following you can see my files.

**login.js**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.


document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user != null){

      var email_id = user.email;
      document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + email_id;

    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.

    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";

  }
});

function login(){

console.log("login");
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();
  console.log("logout");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container login-container" id="login_div">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 login-form">
                    <h3>Zugriff auf deinen Account</h3>
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="email_field" class="form-control" placeholder="Emailadresse *" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" id="password_field" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort *" value="" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" onclick="login()" class="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <a href="#" class="ForgetPwd">Passwort vergessen?</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        <div id="user_div" class="loggedin-div">
            <h3>Welcome User</h3>
            <p id="user_para">Welcome to Firebase web login Example. You're currently logged in.</p>
            <button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
        </div>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>


<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    ...
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
```

Thank you for your help in advance! I am looking forward to reading your answers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check out you have enabled email/password sign-in in the firebase console and add authorized your domain
Then look at the request and response in the "Network" tab in DevTools. What does the firebase server respond to you?

Comment: I looked in my network and error 403 no access.
even though I entered and set everything correctly. Thank you.

Comment: In the response must be a message, check it

Comment: The message: `<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>`

Comment: Are you sure this is an auth request? Probably this request trying to get records from the database before you login.
Maybe this will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834520/accessing-the-signed-url-of-firebase-storage-from-browser-says-access-denied